# Get one custom taxonomy category

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I am trying to do something which I thought would be simple but I am at a loss. (I've googled, played with different code, etc.)

I have the following Custom Taxonomy `Job Attributes`.

I have two check box category terms(?):

- paid
- union

  1. I would like to display a taxonomy link for 'union' if union is selected.
  2. I would like to display a taxonomy link for 'union' if union AND paid is selected.

In other words, I would like to ignore that 'paid' is selected.

Breakdown:

1. paid selected = display nothing.
2. union selected = display taxonomy link 'union'.
3. paid AND union are selected = display taxonomy link 'union'.

I am also trying to make this into a short code; I am integrating into something else:

```
function wpv_check_for_union_func() {

// Ive tried a bunch of thing and would appreciate some leads.

}

add_shortcode( 'wpv_check_for_union', 'wpv_check_for_union_func' );
```

Comment: You will have to show us some code to better understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks to me like it boils down to "if `union` is selected, then echo a link to `union`, else do nothing." I think your description is much too complicated. It looks like you can effectively ignore `paid` completely.

```
function wpv_check_for_union_func($attr,$content='') {
  global $post;
  $taxonomy = 'yourtaxslug';

  $union = has_term('union', $taxonomy, $post);

  if ($union) {
    $term_link = get_term_link( 'union', $taxonomy );
    if( !is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
      return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">union</a>';
    }
  }

}

add_shortcode( 'wpv_check_for_union', 'wpv_check_for_union_func' );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is actually very close to what I was using but was not working.  I was over thinking it a bit, and I wasn't thinking about using a 'if' statement which made the difference.  Thank you again.